# What is the original paper introducing the Variational Quantum Eigensolver?

Tags: resource-request, vqe, optimization

My question is very simple. I am looking for original paper where Variational Quantum Eigensolver (VQE) has been introduced. After some Googling I was able to find many applications of VQE and its modification, however, not the desired paper. I appreciate any help.

Comment: [This](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2111.05176.pdf) might be helpful.

Comment: @narip: Thanks for very useful article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A variational eigenvalue solver on a photonic quantum processor](https://doi.org/10.1038/ncomms5213) - Peruzzo et al.